# Solving for an unknown in an exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve for m in the following equality
$$a\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-(m+d)}}{c}\right)(1+c)=b\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}}{c}\right)(1+c)$$
I have worked it to the following
$$m = -log_{1+c}\left(\frac{b-b(1+c)^{-m}}{a}+1\right)$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you try to replace (1+c)^m or (1+c)^-m by X and solve for x?

Comment: Your suggestion led me to the solution which was to change the (1+c)^-(m+d) to (1+c)^-m*(1+c)^-d<br>Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Moti's suggestion, I have been able to solve the equation.

Original Equation:

$$a\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-(m+d)}}{c}\right)(1+c)=b\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}}{c}\right)(1+c)$$

Apply property of exponents: $a^{x+y} = a^x\times a^y$

$$a\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}}{c}\right)(1+c)=b\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}}{c}\right)(1+c)$$

Divided both sides by $(1+c)$

$$a\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}}{c}\right)=b\left(\frac{1-(1+c)^{-m}}{c}\right)$$

Distributed $a$ and $b$

$$\frac{a-a(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}}{c}=\frac{b-b(1+c)^{-m}}{c}$$

Multiplied both sides by $c$

$$a-a(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}=b-b(1+c)^{-m}$$

Subtracted $a$ from both sides

$$a(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}=b-b(1+c)^{-m}-a$$

Added $b(1+c)^{-m}$ to both sides

$$a(1+c)^{-m}(1+c)^{-d}+b(1+c)^{-m}=b-a$$

Factored out $(1+c)^{-m}$

$$(1+c)^{-m}\left(b-a(1+c)^{-d}\right)=b-a$$

Divided both sides by $b-a(1+c)^{-d}$

$$(1+c)^{-m}=\frac{b-a}{b-a(1+c)^{-d}}$$

Applied the natural $\log$ to both sides

$$\ln\left((1+c)^{-m}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{b-a}{b-a(1+c)^{-d}}\right)$$

Applied log rule: $\log_a(x^b)=b\times\log_a(x)$

$$(-m)\ln(1+c)=\ln\left(\frac{b-a}{b-a(1+c)^{-d}}\right)$$

Divided both sides by $\ln(1+c)$ and multiplied by $-1$

$$m=-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{b-a}{b-a(1+c)^{-d}}\right)}{\ln(1+c)}$$